# Conceptual - Devices Fingerprint Reader

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint

Is that possible to program a Samsung Device fingerprint reader to read and store multiple fingerprints for third-party app use, not for device functionality? 
I would store it in my own database. In other words, I am interested in using the fingerprint reader to read and save in my database multiple users fingerprints through an app.

If anyone knows someone capable of doing this I am interested in the service.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use external fingerprint sensor with specific Android SDK or a a specific Android device embedding fingerprint sensor with specific SDK.

It's not possible with consumer-market Android devices.

Here features of Samsung Pass SDK:

> You can use the Pass SDK to ([source](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass#techdocs)):
>
> - Request fingerprint recognition
> - Cancel fingerprint recognition requests
> - Verify whether the fingerprint of the current user matches the fingerprint registered on the device
> - Register fingerprints through the Enroll screen
> - Get the index of the identified fingerprint from the array of registered fingerprints
> - Set the index of the fingerprint for recognition requests
> - Add a title for the user interface
> - Add a logo icon for the user interface
> - Set the transparency of elements outside the user interface
> - Set whether the user interface is dismissed or not when touching elements outside it
> - Broadcast actions when registered fingerprint is changed
> - Get the guide for poor quality
> - Set the button for the user interface
> - Change the standby string for the user interface